# format multi-table SQL query to PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a multi-table SQL query (below) that works to get the answer I want, however I need to code the same query into an anonymous PL/SQL block. I have tried a number of ways, but not getting a similar valid output. Can anyone please tell me how you would handle this (or just some pointers on how best to proceed)? Thanks!

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT zip, count(purchase) as total_sales_in_zip
FROM sales s 
  JOIN items i 
    ON s.sale_id = i.sale_id  
  JOIN customers c 
    ON s.cust_id = c.cust_id
GROUP BY zip
ORDER BY total_sales_in_zip DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```

The output result is:

```
ZIP     TOTAL_SALES_IN_ZIP                                                             
-----   -------------------
48864                    38
```

Comment: anonymous PL/SQL block what does it mean?

Comment: Anonymous Pl/sql block means just like a procedure/function/simple block without any name. It does not have `CREATE STATEMENT` to label its name hence anonymous

Comment: PL/SQL blocks *do* things, rather than *report* things. You could have it return a ref cursor, and from Oracle 12.1 it could return it implicitly depending on the client application, but I am still wondering what you need to achieve with this. Also, what does “multi-table” have to do with the question?

Answer (score 2):

Although your query looks pointless. As its a simple join query with no restrictions and extra complex filters to work on. If you just add a `BEGIN` at presql and `END` at postsql, It would be a valid anonymous Pl/sql block.

```
 DECLARE
    v_zip Sales.zip%TYPE :=&v_zip;
    v_total_sales_in_zip varchar2(200);
 BEGIN

    SELECT v_zip, count(purchase) 
        as 
       total_sales_in_zip  into 
        v_total_sales_in_zip
      FROM sales s 
      JOIN items i 
       ON s.sale_id = i.sale_id  
     JOIN customers c 
      ON s.cust_id = c.cust_id 
       GROUP BY v_zip
      ORDER BY total_sales_in_zip DESC)
      WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    dbms_output.putline("ZIP CODE"|| v_zip  ||"Total Sales in Zip : "|| v_total_sales_in_zip);
 END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I was able to resolve this in an SQL query, but struggling some with doing the same in PL/SQL, which is newer to me. Still have a lot to read up and practice with PL/SQL and getting the options and syntax down.